# Obtaining multiple lines in a file after matching 1st line containing special characters

Tags: string, perl, awk

I have a perl script that I am creating and I need to obtain several lines from a file. I know the first line I want to match and I have it in a string. String contains...

```
DEFINE QLOCAL ('NAME.OF.QUEUE1') +
```

I need to match the line above to the 1st line of the block of text I want to obtain and dump everything up to the next blank line to an array.

Example Data File

```
DEFINE QLOCAL ('NAME.OF.QUEUE0') +
  DESCR('Description') +
  PUT(DISABLED) +
  GET(DISABLED) +
  RETURN

DEFINE QLOCAL ('NAME.OF.QUEUE1') +
  DESCR('Description') +
  PUT(ENABLED) +
  GET(ENABLED) +
  RETURN

DEFINE QREMOTE ('NAME.OF.QUEUE1') +
  DESCR('Description') +
  PUT(ENABLED) +
  GET(DISABLED) +
  MAXDEPTH(1000) +
  RETURN
```

I have been trying to get the following awk command to work

```
awk '/$Object/' RS= file.txt
```

If $Object is just NAME.OF.QUEUE1 I am able to get results but it is for both QLOCAL and QREMOTE. I need to match the entire line, not just NAME.OF.QUEUE1. If I set $Object to equal the entire 1st line I get no results.

This is what I have been calling from Perl and not getting it to work

```
my $Object="DEFINE QLOCAL ('NAME.OF.QUEUE1') +\n";
my @ObjectValues = `awk '/$Object/' RS= file.txt`;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Assume that you have a shell variable `Object`:

```
Object="DEFINE QLOCAL ('NAME.OF.QUEUE1') +"
```

note that no ending `\n` in the `Object`, then you can:

```
awk -v o="$Object" -v RS= -F'\n' '$1==o' file
```

with your file, it outputs:

```
kent$  awk -v o="$Object" -v RS= -F'\n' '$1==o' file
DEFINE QLOCAL ('NAME.OF.QUEUE1') +
  DESCR('Description') +
  PUT(ENABLED) +
  GET(ENABLED) +
  RETURN
```